# When should element.all(locator).then(thenFunction) or element.all(locator) be used?

Tags: typescript, protractor, angular-e2e

In protractor, what's the difference between ([source](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/5d8da049815ffc104e6eca71d2ecaec51b00f520/spec/basic/locators_spec.js#L332)):

**Example 1**

```js
const allOptions = element.all(by.options('fruit for fruit in fruits'));
expect(await allOptions.count()).toEqual(4);
```

and ([source](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/5d8da049815ffc104e6eca71d2ecaec51b00f520/spec/basic/locators_spec.js#L100)):

**Example 2**

```js
const arr = await element.all(by.model('color'));
expect(arr.length).toEqual(3);
```

Why if I do...

**Example 3**

```js
let allOptions = await element.all(by.css('.mat-option-text > span'));
let firstOption = allOptions.first();
```

...I get this static typescript error?

> Property 'first' does not exist on type 'any[] | ElementFinder[]'. Property 'first' does not exist on type 'any[]'.ts(2339)

---

What is the correct usage of [element.all(locator).then(thenFunction)](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.then) and [element.all(locator)](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder)?

Comment: I don't think you should use `await` before the `element.all` part. Unless it's a promise that needs to be resolved (like `count`).

Comment: @JoaquinCasco So `await` in Example 2 is useless? Am I right?

Comment: yes. The `await` should be right before the `arr.length` -> `expect(await arr.length).toEqual(3);`

Comment: @JoaquinCasco `arr.length` doesn't return a promise, can you explain me why we need `await` before it in this case? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially, `element.all` returns an [ElementArrayFinder](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder) object but `await element.all` will return an array of [ElementFinder](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder) objects.

An awaited ElementArrayFinder is simple an array of ElementFinder objects and therefore can call all existing [array methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#) (such as length). An unawaited ElementArrayFinder is a special object defined withing protractor and has special methods available to it (such as count(), get() and first()).

The methods available to ElementArrayFinder are listed in the protractor api.

### Example

For this example go to the page https://angular.io/. `$([class="button hero-cta"])` only finds one element on this page

**console.log(element.all('[class="button hero-cta"]'))** will return the following ElementArrayFinder object

```
ElementArrayFinder {
  browser_: ProtractorBrowser {
    controlFlow: [Function],
    schedule: [Function],
    setFileDetector: [Function],
    getExecutor: [Function],
    getSession: [Function],
    getCapabilities: [Function],
    quit: [Function],
    actions: [Function],
    touchActions: [Function],
    executeScript: [Function],
    executeAsyncScript: [Function],
    call: [Function],
    wait: [Function],
    sleep: [Function],
    getWindowHandle: [Function],
    getAllWindowHandles: [Function],
    getPageSource: [Function],
    close: [Function],
    getCurrentUrl: [Function],
    getTitle: [Function],
    findElementInternal_: [Function],
    findElementsInternal_: [Function],
    takeScreenshot: [Function],
    manage: [Function],
    switchTo: [Function],
    driver: thenableWebDriverProxy {
      flow_: [ControlFlow],
      session_: [ManagedPromise],
      executor_: [Executor],
      fileDetector_: null,
      onQuit_: undefined,
      cancel: [Function],
      then: [Function: bound then],
      catch: [Function: bound then],
      getNetworkConnection: [Function],
      setNetworkConnection: [Function],
      toggleAirplaneMode: [Function],
      toggleWiFi: [Function],
      toggleData: [Function],
      toggleLocationServices: [Function],
      getGeolocation: [Function],
      setGeolocation: [Function],
      getCurrentDeviceActivity: [Function],
      startDeviceActivity: [Function],
      getAppiumSettings: [Function],
      setAppiumSettings: [Function],
      getCurrentContext: [Function],
      selectContext: [Function],
      getScreenOrientation: [Function],
      setScreenOrientation: [Function],
      isDeviceLocked: [Function],
      lockDevice: [Function],
      unlockDevice: [Function],
      installApp: [Function],
      isAppInstalled: [Function],
      removeApp: [Function],
      pullFileFromDevice: [Function],
      pullFolderFromDevice: [Function],
      pushFileToDevice: [Function],
      listContexts: [Function],
      uploadFile: [Function],
      switchToParentFrame: [Function],
      fullscreen: [Function],
      sendAppToBackground: [Function],
      closeApp: [Function],
      getAppStrings: [Function],
      launchSession: [Function],
      resetApp: [Function],
      hideSoftKeyboard: [Function],
      getDeviceTime: [Function],
      openDeviceNotifications: [Function],
      rotationGesture: [Function],
      shakeDevice: [Function],
      sendChromiumCommand: [Function],
      sendChromiumCommandAndGetResult: [Function]
    },
    element: [Function: element] { all: [Function] },
    '$': [Function],
    '$$': [Function],
    baseUrl: '',
    getPageTimeout: 10000,
    params: {},
    resetUrl: 'data:text/html,<html></html>',
    debugHelper: DebugHelper { browserUnderDebug_: [Circular] },
    ready: ManagedPromise {
      flow_: [ControlFlow],
      stack_: null,
      parent_: null,
      callbacks_: null,
      state_: 'fulfilled',
      handled_: true,
      value_: [Circular],
      queue_: null
    },
    trackOutstandingTimeouts_: true,
    mockModules_: [ [Object] ],
    ExpectedConditions: ProtractorExpectedConditions { browser: [Circular] },
    plugins_: Plugins {
      setup: [Function],
      onPrepare: [Function],
      teardown: [Function],
      postResults: [Function],
      postTest: [Function],
      onPageLoad: [Function],
      onPageStable: [Function],
      waitForPromise: [Function],
      waitForCondition: [Function],
      pluginObjs: [],
      assertions: {},
      resultsReported: false
    },
    allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
    getProcessedConfig: [Function],
    forkNewDriverInstance: [Function],
    restart: [Function],
    restartSync: [Function],
    internalRootEl: '',
    internalIgnoreSynchronization: true
  },
  getWebElements: [Function: getWebElements],
  locator_: name(name) {
    return By.css('*[name="' + escapeCss(name) + '"]');
  } {
    using: 'css selector',
    value: '[class="button hero-cta"]'
  },
  actionResults_: null,
  click: [Function],
  sendKeys: [Function],
  getTagName: [Function],
  getCssValue: [Function],
  getAttribute: [Function],
  getText: [Function],
  getSize: [Function],
  getLocation: [Function],
  isEnabled: [Function],
  isSelected: [Function],
  submit: [Function],
  clear: [Function],
  isDisplayed: [Function],
  getId: [Function],
  takeScreenshot: [Function]
}
```

**console.log(await element.all('[class="button hero-cta"]'))**   will return an array of ElementFinder Objects

```
[
  ElementFinder {
    browser_: ProtractorBrowser {
      controlFlow: [Function],
      schedule: [Function],
      setFileDetector: [Function],
      getExecutor: [Function],
      getSession: [Function],
      getCapabilities: [Function],
      quit: [Function],
      actions: [Function],
      touchActions: [Function],
      executeScript: [Function],
      executeAsyncScript: [Function],
      call: [Function],
      wait: [Function],
      sleep: [Function],
      getWindowHandle: [Function],
      getAllWindowHandles: [Function],
      getPageSource: [Function],
      close: [Function],
      getCurrentUrl: [Function],
      getTitle: [Function],
      findElementInternal_: [Function],
      findElementsInternal_: [Function],
      takeScreenshot: [Function],
      manage: [Function],
      switchTo: [Function],
      driver: [thenableWebDriverProxy],
      element: [Function],
      '$': [Function],
      '$$': [Function],
      baseUrl: '',
      getPageTimeout: 10000,
      params: {},
      resetUrl: 'data:text/html,<html></html>',
      debugHelper: [DebugHelper],
      ready: [ManagedPromise],
      trackOutstandingTimeouts_: true,
      mockModules_: [Array],
      ExpectedConditions: [ProtractorExpectedConditions],
      plugins_: [Plugins],
      allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
      getProcessedConfig: [Function],
      forkNewDriverInstance: [Function],
      restart: [Function],
      restartSync: [Function],
      internalRootEl: '',
      internalIgnoreSynchronization: true
    },
    then: null,
    parentElementArrayFinder: ElementArrayFinder {
      browser_: [ProtractorBrowser],
      getWebElements: [Function: getWebElements],
      locator_: [name(name) {
    return By.css('*[name="' + escapeCss(name) + '"]');
  }],
      actionResults_: null,
      click: [Function],
      sendKeys: [Function],
      getTagName: [Function],
      getCssValue: [Function],
      getAttribute: [Function],
      getText: [Function],
      getSize: [Function],
      getLocation: [Function],
      isEnabled: [Function],
      isSelected: [Function],
      submit: [Function],
      clear: [Function],
      isDisplayed: [Function],
      getId: [Function],
      takeScreenshot: [Function]
    },
    elementArrayFinder_: ElementArrayFinder {
      browser_: [ProtractorBrowser],
      getWebElements: [Function: getWebElements],
      locator_: [name(name) {
    return By.css('*[name="' + escapeCss(name) + '"]');
  }],
      actionResults_: null,
      click: [Function],
      sendKeys: [Function],
      getTagName: [Function],
      getCssValue: [Function],
      getAttribute: [Function],
      getText: [Function],
      getSize: [Function],
      getLocation: [Function],
      isEnabled: [Function],
      isSelected: [Function],
      submit: [Function],
      clear: [Function],
      isDisplayed: [Function],
      getId: [Function],
      takeScreenshot: [Function]
    },
    click: [Function],
    sendKeys: [Function],
    getTagName: [Function],
    getCssValue: [Function],
    getAttribute: [Function],
    getText: [Function],
    getSize: [Function],
    getLocation: [Function],
    isEnabled: [Function],
    isSelected: [Function],
    submit: [Function],
    clear: [Function],
    isDisplayed: [Function],
    getId: [Function],
    takeScreenshot: [Function]
  }
]
.


1 spec, 0 failures
Finished in 3.881 seconds

[13:33:25] I/local - Shutting down selenium standalone server.
[13:33:25] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[13:33:25] I/launcher - chrome #01 passed

C:\ProtractorProjects\ddg>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have clear understanding what each one does...

`element(...)` - returns ElementFinder (one element)

`element.all(...)` - returns ElementArrayFinder (many elements)

both are used to point to the element. Then you'd like to interact with them - click, get count, get text etc... whatever you would want to do with them are Promises. So

`element().count()` or `element().getText()` - return a Promise

Promise essentially is nothing... because it may be resolved later, may be pending, may be rejected (it's not nothing in fact, but easier to think of it this way)

`await` keyword resolves a Promise and returns a value, which will be a number for `.count()` or a string for `.getText()`

so what you should be doing is this

```
// declare an element
let elem = element(by.css('some css'));

// then you declare a promise and resolve it
let value = await elem.getText()
// or
await elem.click()
```